# How to create an object with link to nested object from id's in POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get my head around how to cope with nested models in django-rest-framework (DRF). I have read [this part of the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects), which deals with writing a serializer that can save nested objects, but it's not exactly what I want. In a post I have the id's of related (many-to-many) objects.

Example:
Lets say that I have a Match (think soccer, tennis) and a match is between 2 teams, and the teams consist of players. I want to sent a `POST` with the match-info and the player-ids. If the players have played before there is already a team, otherwise we should make the team.

If player 1 played game 4 against player 2, the POST would look something like

```
team_1[player_1_id]:1  // 1st player of team 1 is user 1
team_2[player_1_id]:2  // 1st player of team 2 is user 2
game:4
```

The fact that all sorts of stuff needs to be done I thought maybe the `view` was a good place: I need to shuffle around some data before it's ready for a serializer anyway; but how do I start?

I can override the `perform_create` to do magic like so:

```
class MatchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Match.objects.all()
  serializer_class = MatchSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    // get the user ids form the post
    // find if there is are teams, otherwise create the teams
    // get team ids from above
    // add team ids to data so serializer kan save
    serializer.save()
```

So I need to find out

- how to get the id's from the post
- how to get the right team-ids (and possibly create them first)
- how to pass those on the the serializer.

**Specifically what of these functions can be done by using the in-place functions of DRF and/or the ModelViewSet. I'm trying to learn the framework here as well :)**

The models look like this. I'm not looking to save a complete nested object, so I don't think I need to add a specific `create` here?

```
class Match(models.Model):
  game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
  teams = ManyToManyField(Team, through='MatchTeams')
```

the other models that might be relevant are;

```
class MatchTeams(models.Model):
  match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
  team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Team(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField(max_length=128)
  users = ManyToManyField(User, through='TeamUsers')
```

Comment: I assume `team2` in the post data should contain the player2 id?

Comment: @Sayse The id's are per team, so not per se: Its not clear from this minimized example, but it's defined as the first player from the second team (so if the team had 2 players, then you'd get a player 2 as well). That's why there's two player-id-1 's in the post. One for each team :)

Comment: Right ok, yes that makes sense. I'm not sure I have enough time right now to provide a full answer but you might find the `def create(self, request)` method a lot easier to work with since essentially you'll be doing the a lot of the same work as if it were a django view - allowing you to use `get_or_create` etc

Comment: @Sayse i'll look in to that. Another option might be to create a completely different endpoint (not a modelviewset) and add custom code there, but I'm not sure that's the cleanest django/DRF way.

Comment: If you're going to look down that route then you might also want to look into the  [`list_route` and `detail_route` decorators](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) - "If you have ad-hoc methods that you need to be routed to, you can mark them as requiring routing using the @detail_route or @list_route decorators."

Comment: @Sayse yeah. still hoping for a solution closer to the django-rest-framework code though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make a special serializer:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Something like this:

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    player_1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    player_2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            team = Team.objects.filter(Q(users__id=player_1 & users__id=player_2))
        except Team.DoesNotExcist:
            team = Team.objects.create()
            team.users.add(player_1)
            team.users.add(player_2)
            team.save()
        match = super(serializers.Serializer, self)
        match.teams.add(team)
        # Something like this, but you have to post both team members at once. Can be made so you don't have to oc. You also might want to check the count of teams before adding them :-)
        return match

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # same as create but on a given match?
        return instance
```

Does that work for your needs? Best way is to solve this kind of stuff in Serializers, thats where they are for, converting the request fields to the proper objects / fields.

That said, if you want to do something simple, there is always `self.request` you can access in your `ModelViewSet`

Comment: So I make a specific endpoint (`ModelViewSet`) that uses this serializer and handle all the logic here. sounds good. I was hung up on having serializers for my models, but that doesn't need to be the case obviously. good point.

Comment: minor question though: the `ModelViewSet` seems based on a specific model, which isn't really here in this case, right? I just have the serializer and the view. What kind of View should I define that will let me post? Not much else is needed I guess at this point?